# Can not open links

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://ias.in.tum.de/kb/wiki/index.php/Coordinate_systems

all links like http://ias.in.tum.de/kb/wiki/ never open with me !!
so What is the problem

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45270/can-not-open-links/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-10-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2012-10-07**:
Please tag questions with the name of the package or stack so that the maintainers can get email notifications

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-07**:
It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indeed the wiki is down. You should contact people at [IAS, TUM](http://ias.in.tum.de/) to see if they can fix the problem.

I am not sure whether they check ROS Answers regularly so contacting them directly is probably the better option.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1